# How to reload a nested route in React react-router-dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When I'm in a nested page (for example: baseUrl/dashboard/patients) and I refresh the page it will always redirect me to baseUrl/dashboard. Is is possible when I refresh the page it will take me back to (baseUrl/dashboard/patients)? and How?

```js
    <Fragment>
      <ToastContainer />
      <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route 
              exact path = '/login' 
              element={
                !isAuthenticated ? <Login setAuth={setAuth}/> : 
                <Navigate to ="/dashboard"/> 
                }/>
            <Route 
              exact path = '/register' 
              element={
                !isAuthenticated ? <Register setAuth={setAuth}/> : 
                <Navigate to ="/login"/>
                }/>
            <Route 
              path = '/dashboard' 
              element={isAuthenticated ? <Dashboard setAuth={setAuth}/> :  // Should return to the current page after reload
              <Navigate to ="/login"/>}>
                <Route index element = {<About />} />
                <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
                <Route path="analytics" element={<Analytics />} />
                <Route path="appointments" element={<Appointments />} />
                <Route path="comment" element={<Comment />} />
                <Route path="history" element={<History />} />
                <Route path="patients" element={<Patients />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Fragment>
```